# IIS requiring Windows Authentication on some pages of a Web Forms site?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a really strange problem, when I am working on my own machine and pointing my local hosts file to a domain and have it use my IIS instance as a server it pops up a Windows Login and denies access to that page. This is the strangest thing and is only happening when using a local IIS.

Does anyone know why this is happening and the solution to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason was reports is a reserved name.

Comment: Should have noticed that myself, as i have had the same problem. Btw you can accept your own anwser after a while

Answer (score 0):

If this is at work, it could be an Internet Explorer policy making sure it does not try to automatically authenticate itself.

Make sure the localhost in Internet Explorer (or whatever browser you use) has localhost as a trusted site and allows it for authentication.

Comment: This is only happening on one page of my project and it is driving me nuts. I tried that and it is still requiring.